# How to get column sum in the matrix returned by sklearn count vectorizer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

How to get the sum of any given column in the term frequency matrix returned by sklearn `CountVectorizer`?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

corpus = [ 'This is a sentence',
           'Another sentence is here',
           'Wait for another sentence',
           'The sentence is coming',
           'The sentence has come'
         ]

x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

For example I want to find out the frequency of `sentence` in the matrix. So I want the sum of the `sentence` column. I couldn't figure out a way to do this:

- For example I tried `x['sentence'].sum()` but that didn't help
- I also tried converting this to a pandas dataframe and computing the sum, but I shouldn't need to convert this matrix to a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Get the position of your term in the `feature_names()` list from CountVectorizer.
2. Use the position to sum all that column in the CSR matrix (`x`, in your case).

Code:

```
import numpy as np

term_to_sum = 'sentence'    
index_term = vectorizer.get_feature_names().index(term_to_sum)

s = np.sum(x[:, index_term])  # here you get the sum
```